# Populating Class Properties from class Initialization using Visual Studio Helpers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut

I have Created class

```
public Class1
{

}
```

After that I have code which initializes Anonymous method like below

```
var resultObj = new 
{
    Prop1 = 25.0,
    Prop2 = "Foo Bar Baz",
    Prop3 = "5",
    Prop4 = 22.025,
    Prop5 = DateTime.Now
};
```

Now I would like to convert this anonymous class to typed class like below

```
var resultObj = new Class1
{
    Prop1 = 25.0,
    Prop2 = "Foo Bar Baz",
    Prop3 = "5",
    Prop4 = 22.025,
    Prop5 = DateTime.Now
};
```

however class properties are not yet exists. I can declare them one by one, I may also use Resharper to Generate them automatically (again one-by-one) by pressing ALT + Enter / Ctrl + .

But, I am looking for shortcut for generating Properties automatically.

Is there any extension/tool/feature which provides this?

Comment: [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Convert_Anonymous_to_Named_Type.html)?

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2017 you can generate class with it's properties. Just do not declare class first and click Alt + . on a `Class1`

[Vs 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXT0D.png)